# Return Type of Timestamp from Firestore and comparing to DateTime.now() in Flutter

Tags: firebase, dart, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

**EDIT --------->

Additional info. It is possible that I am going about it all wrong. I am trying to achieve the image below. Is an infinite scrolling "calendar" that shows a feed for the corresponding day. I'm beginning to think this is not a tab view issue and it needs to be done some other way.

[image]

------------------>

I'm creating an app that creates a StreamBuilder in Flutter that relies on comparing a date to return Firestore data.

I've created an array of possible date tab values. When the user selects that tab I need to compare the DATE ONLY - no timestamp and show a stream of games that have a matching date field in local time.

I have multiple tabs with one changing view so it isn't a 1:1 ratio of tabs to widgets but the tab needs to control the state of the widget by returning the date value at a clicked index and setting that to stateDate.

Also it would be great to start the user selected on the tab that is todays date.

```
var datesList = [];
var _stateDate = DateTime.now();

initState(){
  for (int i = -14; i < 57; i++) {
    DateTime date = _stateDate;
    date = date.add(Duration(days: i));
    datesList.add(date);
  }
}
```

------------------------------------------------------>

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return DefaultTabController(
    length: dateList.length,
  child: Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      bottom: const PreferredSize(
        preferredSize: Size.zero,
        child: TabBar(
          tabs: <Widget>[
            _buildTabs(),
          ],
          isScrollable: true,
        ),
      ),
    ),
    body: TabBarView(
      children: <Widget>[
        _buildSchedule()
      ],
    ),
  ),
 );
}


@override
  Widget _buildSchedule() {
    return Container(
      child: Center(
        child: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
            stream: Firestore.instance
               .collection('schedule')
               .where('time', isEqualTo: _stateDate) 
               .orderBy('date')
               .snapshots(),
            builder:
                (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
              if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                return const Text('Loading...');
              }

          return ListView.builder(
            itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) =>
                _buildScheduleItem(context, snapshot.data.documents[index]),
          );
        }),
      ),
    );
   }
```

[image]

Any help would be great. Maybe I am just thinking about it all wrong.

Comment: Could you please provide sample data for a document in the  `schedule` collection that clearly shows fields and data types.

Comment: `Date.now()` returns the integer number of milliseconds since unix epoch.  If your `time` field is another other than that, it won't work.  The the types of data must match.

Comment: My time field is what ever Firestore return for a "Timestamp" which I haven't been able to find in there documentation. I believe that when I get the object back it does return the milliseconds since unix epoch. I've been messing with the stream and I got that to work. Now it is a matter of connecting a tabView to control the view underneath it. My understanding is it has to be a one to one ratio using Tabs so I might have to come up with another solution.

Comment: @DennisAlund added picture in post.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
DateTime _now = DateTime.now();
DateTime _start = DateTime(_now.year, _now.month, _now.day, 0, 0);
DateTime _end = DateTime(_now.year, _now.month, _now.day, 23, 59, 59);


stream: Firestore.instance
           .collection('schedule')
           .where('date', isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: _start) 
           .where('date', isLessThanOrEqualTo: _end) 
           .orderBy('date')
           .snapshots(),
```

Comment: oh this makes sense. Just sandwich the time of the current day. I'll give this a try! Thank you!

Comment: you have any idea how I might implement this with a horizontal scroll view in the image above?

Comment: from your streambuilder call  'builder:  (context, snapshot) {" and then inside of there call a ListView.builder with scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal and use snapshot.data.documents as your source