# Flutter: query Firestore document by timestamp

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to query Firestore documents by a Timestamp field (e.g. between a start and end date).
Timestamp field returns something like `Timestamp(seconds=1599170400, nanoseconds=0)`.

I have a Unix timestamp (in seconds) in my app which I like to compare this to (using *isLessThan:*), but the value in Firestore apparently is inside this Timestamp object.

How would I go about comparing these two timestamps?

An alternative would be to query all documents and compare afterwards, but I would like to filter the documents in the query itself.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Firestore query by date range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47000854/firestore-query-by-date-range)

Comment: Incase anyone is struggling here is the solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54014679/return-type-of-timestamp-from-firestore-and-comparing-to-datetime-now-in-flutt

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To compare a `Timestamp` in the database with a milliseconds-since-the-epoch value, you can create a `Timestamp` object based on that value:

```
var timestamp = Timestamp.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(1599573193925);
```

Then you can use this in the query against the value in the database:

```
Firestore.instance
.collection('items')
.orderBy('Timestamp', descending: true).startAt([timestamp])
```

Or (my usual method):

```
Firestore.instance
.collection('items')
.where("Timestamp", isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: timestamp)
```